# Correlated Subquery in MySQL unable to include "column" in main where stmt

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using the following query, to include a correlated subquery, I would like to be able to find records from the main query where PhotoCount (which is the subquery) are > # i.e., > 1 or >5

I have tried doing

WHERE PhotoCount > #
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(operatorID) FROM tbl_photos p WHERE p.operatorID =  aoh.operatorID AND p.img_creator = 'Daniël E. Cronk') > #

However, all of these yield "unknown column" error

I have tried adding in @PhotoCount:= and then doing WHERE PhotoCount but this yields No results.

```
SELECT af.frameID, af.msn AS afMSN, af.ln AS afLN, af.aircraft_type AS toestelA, af.aircraft_cat AS afAircraftCat, af.airframe_status, aoh.operatorID, aoh.aircraftframeID, aoh.msn, aoh.ln, aoh.lvmID, aoh.toestel, aoh.aircraft_cat, aoh.reg, aoh.delivered, aoh.delivery_comment, aoh.engines, aoh.configuration, aoh.fleet_number, aoh.aircraft_name, aoh.special_colors, aoh.comments, aoh.exit_date, aoh.last_updated, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID AS lvmid, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij AS lvmnaam, lvm.sm_logo, (SELECT COUNT(operatorID) FROM tbl_photos p WHERE p.operatorID =  aoh.operatorID AND p.img_creator = 'Daniël E. Cronk') AS PhotoCount

            FROM tbl_aircraft_frame af

            LEFT JOIN tbl_aircraft_operator_history aoh
            ON af.msn = aoh.msn AND af.aircraft_cat = aoh.aircraft_cat

            LEFT JOIN tbl_toestel t
            ON af.aircraft_cat = t.toestelID

            LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
            ON aoh.lvmID = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: And simplify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use a column from the `SELECT`you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT 
    af.frameID,
    af.msn AS afMSN,
    af.ln AS afLN,
    af.aircraft_type AS toestelA,
    af.aircraft_cat AS afAircraftCat,
    af.airframe_status,
    aoh.operatorID,
    aoh.aircraftframeID,
    aoh.msn,
    aoh.ln,
    aoh.lvmID,
    aoh.toestel,
    aoh.aircraft_cat,
    aoh.reg,
    aoh.delivered,
    aoh.delivery_comment,
    aoh.engines,
    aoh.configuration,
    aoh.fleet_number,
    aoh.aircraft_name,
    aoh.special_colors,
    aoh.comments,
    aoh.exit_date,
    aoh.last_updated,
    lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID AS lvmid,
    lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij AS lvmnaam,
    lvm.sm_logo,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(operatorID)
        FROM
            tbl_photos p
        WHERE
            p.operatorID = aoh.operatorID
                AND p.img_creator = 'Daniël E. Cronk') AS PhotoCount
FROM
    tbl_aircraft_frame af
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_aircraft_operator_history aoh ON af.msn = aoh.msn
        AND af.aircraft_cat = aoh.aircraft_cat
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_toestel t ON af.aircraft_cat = t.toestelID
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm ON aoh.lvmID = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID
HAVING PhotoCount > 10
```

Comment: thank you. I never knew that was possible. I appreciate your response.

Comment: For more speed, turn the query inside out -- Find ids for photos with Count>10, _then_ join to everything else.